# Some applications toolbars and menus are very tiny

Tags: 19.04, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu not long ago and some of the downloaded applications have a very tiny interface, and you cannot even see the text in the menus. See the screenshot of IrfanView as an example below. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a 4K monitor? Have you checked the font sizes in GNOME Tweak? How about the scaling factor?

Comment: I enabled 150% scaling feature on Ubuntu 19

Answer (score 0):

This is the fault of the application and not Ubuntu. Are you using wine ? If so you can change the theme https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine#Using_Theme.2FSkins

Comment: It's clearly a windows app https://www.fosshub.com/IrfanView.html?dwl=iview454_x64_setup.exe